# Difference between grayscale images represented by 3 channels and 1 channel in CNN?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction

I am classifying images where the color doesn't play any role. So, I grayscaled my images and got just grayscale images. But they are represented by 3 channels. I know, that I can use the following formula:

```
gray_value = R * 0.299 + G * 0.587 + B * 0.114
```

to convert RGB image to grayscale image and get grayscale image with just one channel.

My question is, is there a difference between using grayscale images represented by 3 channels or by 1 channel in CNN (not in code or filters but in results)? Do the results vary depending on the number of channels, even when the images are the same in both cases?

Comment: I am guessing you mean your greyscale images comprise 3 channels whereby R=G=B? I am no expert in CNN, but in general things tend to take 3 times longer if you have 3 channels, rather than 1. There may be other consequences too, hopefully someone cleverer than me will answer :-)

Comment: In terms of accuracy the results must converge to the same.

Comment: @DmytroPrylipko Not really. The model with three channel inputs have more parameters.

Comment: That was my question. Is the accuracy the same? perhaps because of parameters it would be another.

Comment: @MarkSetchell no, the values RGB are not equal. I know it would take more time, my dataset is not very big therefore the time is not a big problem.

Comment: I meant that it must _converge_ to the same accuracy. At some point you stop getting improvements by increasing number of weights if your model is large enough. Since three gray channels convey the same amount of information as one, there should come no difference due to the data only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information given by the 3 channel and the 1 channel gray scale is the same but in terms of weights and biases of the CNN, the CNN coming from 3 channel images will be bigger and so it will take more time to compute.
I would recommend to preproces the images to a 1 channel gray scale and only then use images as input for the CNN.

Comment: It will take more time for processing 3 channels instead of one. But what about the accuracy?

Comment: The information is the same, only splitted in different channels, I think the accuracy will be the same.

Comment: @NiccolòCacciotti Would it affect features generated by CNN if we convert color image to grayscale?